# Como colocar dois forms um do lado do outro?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Boa tarde!

Em um arquivo PHP tem um formulário HTML que contém uma tabela e um `submit`. Tem também um segundo formulário com outra tabela e um 'submit'. Como colocar o segundo formulário ao lado do primeiro sendo que a terceira tabela tem que ficar abaixo das duas primeiras? Segue o código.

```html
<body bgcolor="#FFFFF0">
<form id="localizacao" name="localizacao" method="post" action="rastreamento.php" onsubmit="return validaCampoLoca(); return false;">
  <table width="50%" border="1">
      <tr><div align="center"><img src=img/logo.jpg></div></tr>
   <tr><th colspan="5" align="center" valign="top"><h2>Localizacao de Carga</h2></th>
   </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="50">CNPJ:</td>
      <td width="835"><input name="CNPJ" type="text" id="CNPJ" size="20" maxlength="14" />
        <span class="style1">*</span> <span class="style3">somente n&uacute;meros</span></td>
  <td width="156">Selecione o STATUS:</td>
  <td><select name="status" id="status">
      <option value="0">Recebido</option>
     <option value="1">Em trânsito</option>
     <option value="2">Encerrado</option>
     </select></td>  
    </tr>     
    <tr>
   <td colspan="2"><p>
        <input name="cadastrar" type="submit" id="cadastrar" value="OK" /> 
        <br />
          <input name="limpar" type="reset" id="limpar" value="Limpar!" />
          <br />
          </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
<form id="alteracoes" name="alteracoes" method="post" action="rastreamento.php" onsubmit="return validaCampoAltera(); return false;">  
  <table width="50%" border="1">
   <tr><th colspan="5" align="center" valign="top"><h2>Alteracoes</h2></th></tr>
   <tr>
      <td width="50">VIAGEM:</td>
      <td width="835"><input name="VIAGEM" type="text" id="VIAGEM" size="20" maxlength="14" />        
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width="50">NOVO STATUS:</td>
      <td width="835"><input name="NVSTATUS" type="text" id="NVSTATUS" size="1" maxlength="1" />        
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width="50">EMBARCACAO:</td>
      <td width="835"><input name="EMBARC" type="text" id="EMBARC" size="20" maxlength="10" />        
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width="50">DATA SAIDA:</td>
      <td width="835"><input name="DATSAI" type="text" id="DATSAI" size="20" maxlength="10" />        
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width="50">HORA SAIDA:</td>
      <td width="835"><input name="HORSAI" type="text" id="HORSAI" size="20" maxlength="10" />        
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width="50">DATA CHEGADA:</td>
      <td width="835"><input name="DATCH" type="text" id="DATCH" size="20" maxlength="10" />        
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width="50">HORA CHEGADA:</td>
      <td width="835"><input name="HORCHE" type="text" id="HORCHE" size="20" maxlength="10" />        
   </tr>   
   <tr>
   <td colspan="2"><p>
        <input name="atualizar" type="submit" id="atualizar" value="ATUALIZAR" /> 
        <br />
          </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function validaCampoLoca()
{
if(document.localizacao.CNPJ.value=="")
 {
 alert("O Campo CNPJ é obrigatorio!");
 return false;
 }
else 
return true;
}
function validaCampoAltera()
{
if(document.alteracoes.VIAGEM.value=="")
 {
 alert("O Campo VIAGEM é obrigatório!");
 return false;
 }
else
return true;
}
// Fim do JavaScript que validará os campos obrigatórios!
</script>
 <!-- Lista cada documento de acordo com o CNPJ e o STATUS-->  
<table width="100%" border="1">
 <thead><tr>
 <th align="center">CNPJ</th>
 <th align="center">Data rec</th>
 <th align="center">Tipo Doc</th>
 <th>N&ordm; Doc</th>
 <th>Quant. Vol</th>
 <th>Processo</th>
 <th>Loc. Ent.</th>
 <th>Fornec</th>
 <th>Status</th>
 </tr></thead>
 
 <tbody>
 <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  
  </tr>
  
 </tbody></table>

</body>
```

Comment: Cara, cadê o arquivo de folhas de estilo (CSS)?
A aparência da páginas é definida utilizando este recurso.

Comment: Já que faz uso de tabelas, crie uma tabela com duas colunas e em cada coluna coloque um formulário

Comment: Pesquise sobre CSS flexbox, é de longe a forma mais racional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe o atributo `align="left"` (`<table align="left">`) que faz com que a tabela fique alinhada à esquerda dos elementos seguintes, mas esse atributo se tornou obsoleto no HTML5. Você pode usar `float: left` que as tabelas ficarão lado-a-lado, exceto se a tela for muito estreita onde a largura mínima das tabelas não permita que uma fique ao lado da outra.

Como a última tabela possui largura total de 100%, esta ficará sempre abaixo das duas primeiras (execute o exemplo abaixo em tela cheia):

```css
table{
   float: left;
}
```

```html
<form id="localizacao" name="localizacao" method="post" action="rastreamento.php" onsubmit="return validaCampoLoca(); return false;">
  <table width="50%" border="1">
      <tr><div align="center"><img src=img/logo.jpg></div></tr>
   <tr><th colspan="5" align="center" valign="top"><h2>Localizacao de Carga</h2></th>
   </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="50">CNPJ:</td>
      <td width="835"><input name="CNPJ" type="text" id="CNPJ" size="20" maxlength="14" />
        <span class="style1">*</span> <span class="style3">somente n&uacute;meros</span></td>
  <td width="156">Selecione o STATUS:</td>
  <td><select name="status" id="status">
      <option value="0">Recebido</option>
     <option value="1">Em trânsito</option>
     <option value="2">Encerrado</option>
     </select></td>  
    </tr>     
    <tr>
   <td colspan="2"><p>
        <input name="cadastrar" type="submit" id="cadastrar" value="OK" /> 
        <br />
          <input name="limpar" type="reset" id="limpar" value="Limpar!" />
          <br />
          </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
<form id="alteracoes" name="alteracoes" method="post" action="rastreamento.php" onsubmit="return validaCampoAltera(); return false;">  
  <table width="50%" border="1">
   <tr><th colspan="5" align="center" valign="top"><h2>Alteracoes</h2></th></tr>
   <tr>
      <td width="50">VIAGEM:</td>
      <td width="835"><input name="VIAGEM" type="text" id="VIAGEM" size="20" maxlength="14" />        
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width="50">NOVO STATUS:</td>
      <td width="835"><input name="NVSTATUS" type="text" id="NVSTATUS" size="1" maxlength="1" />        
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width="50">EMBARCACAO:</td>
      <td width="835"><input name="EMBARC" type="text" id="EMBARC" size="20" maxlength="10" />        
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width="50">DATA SAIDA:</td>
      <td width="835"><input name="DATSAI" type="text" id="DATSAI" size="20" maxlength="10" />        
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width="50">HORA SAIDA:</td>
      <td width="835"><input name="HORSAI" type="text" id="HORSAI" size="20" maxlength="10" />        
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width="50">DATA CHEGADA:</td>
      <td width="835"><input name="DATCH" type="text" id="DATCH" size="20" maxlength="10" />        
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width="50">HORA CHEGADA:</td>
      <td width="835"><input name="HORCHE" type="text" id="HORCHE" size="20" maxlength="10" />        
   </tr>   
   <tr>
   <td colspan="2"><p>
        <input name="atualizar" type="submit" id="atualizar" value="ATUALIZAR" /> 
        <br />
          </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
<table width="100%" border="1">
 <thead><tr>
 <th align="center">CNPJ</th>
 <th align="center">Data rec</th>
 <th align="center">Tipo Doc</th>
 <th>N&ordm; Doc</th>
 <th>Quant. Vol</th>
 <th>Processo</th>
 <th>Loc. Ent.</th>
 <th>Fornec</th>
 <th>Status</th>
 </tr></thead>
 
 <tbody>
 <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  
  </tr>
  
 </tbody></table>
```

Comment: Era isso que o sistema precisava. Só uma dúvida, o flexbox também resolveria essa questão?

Comment: Acho que resolveria, mas acho que para uma coisa simples não seja necessário usar flexbox.